# PHP Email Error

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am getting an error even though the script is running successfully. It is doing exactly what I want it to do but I am getting a nasty error.

my code is as follows:

```
<

?php

$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$surname = $_REQUEST['surname'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = md5($_REQUEST['password']);

$con = mysql_connect("*******","**","***");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('****', $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Users (title, firstname, surname, email, username, password, role) VALUES ('$title','$name', '$surname','$email','$username','$password', 'normaluser')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$username = $_REQUEST["username"];
$password = $_REQUEST["password"];
$confirmpass = 'password:';


ini_set ("sendmail_from","Conference@greenwich.com");

$messege = "Hi $name $surname, \n\r\n\r Thanks For Registering.\n\r\n\r Your Username: $username \n\r\n\r Your Password: $password \n\r\n\rRemember To Start Booking Your Desired Meetings!!!";
$to= "$email";
$from = 'welcome@meetings.com';
$subject="Registration Success";
mail($to,$message,$subject,$from);

echo "Thanks $surname, You Have Successfully Registered! </br>  </br>  Please Check Your Email!";



mysql_close($con)
?>
```

the error is : `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\webareas\hj942\CW\meetings\conference\Register\register_success.php on line 67`

line 67 is the line after:

echo "Thanks $surname, You Have Successfully Registered!     Please Check Your Email!";

which is an empty line! it has nothing on it.

any help?

Comment: Is the different typing of `$messege` and `$message` just an error here or also in the productive code?

Comment: -1. Bad question. You aren't actually __reading__ the error message, only telling us that it's "nasty".

Comment: @fkerber, well spotted. thank you

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051107/php-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded

Comment: @user1114080 But this was not the reason for the problem, wasn't it?

Comment: The timeout could just mean it's attempting to connect to a server, and failing.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the beginning of your code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```

Comment: Is this really a good idea? I see no obvious reason why this code should last longer than 30 seconds. Therefore, I think, there must be an error and just increasing the execution time will not solve the initial problem.

Comment: I suspect there's a reason why it's failing - the script shouldn't take more than a small portion of a second to run, so this probably isn't a real fix.

Comment: It really just depends on the server.

Comment: If 30 seconds is not enough to a local network mail server (that can send the mail to its real destination) then the 'solution' should not be to increase the script running time to 10 minutes.

Comment: Perhaps the mail server isn't set up?  There is nothing in the script that will catch mail() errors.

Comment: guys it has now been fixed! there was an error in the naming of one my variables...calm down

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it'll actually be timing out on the `mail(...)` line. Easiest way to test - pop a new line BEFORE and a new line AFTER it like...

```
$subject="Registration Success";
//Hello
mail($to,$message,$subject,$from);
//World    

echo "Than...";
```

Then see what line it says it's timing out on. If it's increased by ONE it's the `mail()` line, if it's by two them I'm wrong!

I would imagine that the mail() function isn't set up correctly in the php configuration of your server. We can easily test that too - create a new php file:

```
<?php
   mail('youremail@yourdomain.com','Test email','Test email');
?>
```

Run that. If that fails then we definitely know you're having `mail()` issues. If it succeeds, let's try plan B.