# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in my php

Tags: php, apache, debian

[I have a blog](http://79.121.121.12:8060/blog/index.php) and [there is the code](https://github.com/PumpkinSeed/blog). This load is very slow and in error.log i got this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in my ../php/controller.php on line 19.

What is the problem? I set the php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 1000M
```

But not working. Apache, Debian, Mysql Thanx for the help.

Comment: Best to try running a php script with `phpinfo()` in on your blog to make sure the settings were actually loaded. If not you can find the list of loaded `.ini` files at the top.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051107/php-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: But I dont understand why my code is to slow. I have only one item in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I given negative index in the view.php to the SQL and it was failed it, but I sloved it.