# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded while exporting pdf

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to export pdf and it works fine when I try to export the pdf localy or from a an other machine in the same network
but when i Try to export the pdf from an other pc not from the same network I get this error message

```
FatalErrorException in WindowsPipes.php line 207: 
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051107/php-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

This is to make sure a bad script don't consume too much resource. To allow your PHP script to run at a longer time, you'll need to increase the maximum execution time limit of PHP scripts using any of the following methods; - See more at: https://www.simplified.guide/php/increase-max-execution-time

Edit your php.ini file and find this line:

```
max_execution_time
```

Change its value to 300:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

Else, you need to add this line at the head of you php page :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //seconds
```

Comment: I have done that and did not solve the problem, I get now this error message: 
ProcessTimedOutException in Process.php line 1226: The process "C:\xampp\htdocs\caleadmin\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --footer-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86ab0667.13821126.html" --header-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86add965.96288464.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a925d7.06923634.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a98471.73130018.pdf"" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

Comment: I found this issues https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/9

Comment: yeah I already passed by that topic 
the problem is when I generate the pdf localy it works just fine 
but when I try to export the same pdf from an external pc I get that error

Comment: See if you do not have two php.ini : A first for " php- fpm " and second for " cli " . The configuration must be bad on the side of php- fpm . If you find this file, add the same configuration. What is your version of php and server?

Comment: I am using xamp with php version 5.6.12

Answer (score 0):

Your loop might be endless. You need to add this at the top of the php page

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

else add this line

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: If you are right and there is an endless loop, this will just allow it to run longer!

Comment: I have done that and did not solve the problem, I get now this error message: 
ProcessTimedOutException in Process.php line 1226: The process "C:\xampp\htdocs\caleadmin\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --footer-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86ab0667.13821126.html" --header-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86add965.96288464.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a925d7.06923634.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a98471.73130018.pdf"" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to maximize your **execution time.**

if you are working on Live server than make a file named as **user.ini** and write following code.  (save user.ini file in **same folder**)

```
max_execution_time = 600 // 600 seconds
```

if you are working on localhost then you can use ini_set() function like this ,

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds
```

Comment: I have done that and did not solve the problem, I get now this error message: 
ProcessTimedOutException in Process.php line 1226: The process "C:\xampp\htdocs\caleadmin\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --footer-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86ab0667.13821126.html" --header-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86add965.96288464.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a925d7.06923634.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a98471.73130018.pdf"" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The most preferable way to do this so you don't have to add it to add those codes to all the pages. Go to your `php.ini` in `C://xampp/php/php.ini` and go to the line that looks like this `max_execution_time = 30` you the change the value to the desired amount of seconds you like save it and restart your XAMPP server

Comment: I have done that and did not solve the problem, I get now this error message: 
ProcessTimedOutException in Process.php line 1226: The process "C:\xampp\htdocs\caleadmin\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe --lowquality --footer-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86ab0667.13821126.html" --header-html "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86add965.96288464.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a925d7.06923634.html" "C:\Windows\TEMP\knp_snappy578f7b86a98471.73130018.pdf"" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you mentioned has nothing to do with PHP's `max_execution_time` ini parameter.

By looking at the tags you have added to your question it seems that you are using the PHP Laravel framework. You are probably using a PHP library which uses `wkhtmltopdf` to generate a PDF (eg. from a HTML content), i.e. [KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle).

Such a library does not use [exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function, which would block the PHP script until either it's done in timely fashion or the [max_execution_time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) is exceeded. Instead it uses the [proc_open](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) function which would execute the `wkhtmltopdf` command and open file pointers for input/output and thus return immediately (so the `max_execution_time` would not be in effect).

If that's the case then the cause of your `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` is strictly related to the library you are using.

If your library are using a process-driven class for executing the `wkhtmltopdf` command then the issue you are describing might share the same cause like the one described by the people using the KnpSnappy library. If that's the case then please check these links, it might help:

- https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle/issues/69
- https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/169

In my case the problem was related to the PHP session and the `cookie` argument, so I configured my library such that I passed the `--cookie` argument to the `wkhtmltopdf` command. Check the [wkhtmltopdf manual](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this slowness is caused by some missing items, like: images, fonts and links.
Try to check if some images are pointing to invalid path.